# Why i am getting 0 kb files when downloading images using curl?

Tags: php, curl, server

i am trying to download images directly on the server from an array of URL's by running a php/curl script. 
but only the last file from array is getting download from the list, rest all images are 0 kb.

```
$image_array = array(url1,url2,url3);
foreach($image_array as $array_element){
    if(isset($array_element)){
        grab_image($array_element, DIRECTORY.basename($array_element));
    }
    sleep(10);
}

function grab_image($url,$saveto){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

https://snag.gy/a80jpC.jpg

Comment: use this function to grab images instead of your's 
``function grab_image($url,$saveto){
file_put_contents($saveto,file_get_contents($url));
}``

Comment: Check for errors from `curl_exec()`.

Comment: no errors from curl_exec()

Comment: @Dimi getting following warnings
Warning: file_get_contents( ): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/abc/public/downloadsimages.php on line 62

Warning: file_get_contents(https://abcd.com/images/G/01/sdfsdfsdfsdf._QL100_.jpg ): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /www/abc/public/downloadsimages.php on line 62

Comment: @atul1039 URL that you provided in question is HTML page. The actual image address is ``https://i.snag.gy/a80jpC.jpg`` Make sure to include 'https://' in your address. it does not work otherwise ``file_get_contents('http://abcd.com/images/G/01/sdfsdfsdfsdf._QL100_.jpg' )``

Comment: @Dimi all the URL's have https in front of them and why only last file getting downloaded and rest of the files are 0 kb in screenshot

Comment: Maybe add `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` and see if that helps.  Could be that there is a redirect.  And `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); var_dump(curl_error($ch));` prior to curl close for debugging to see if any useful info is returned.